# react router dom v6 usenavigate need to refresh page to show new data

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a page /studentprofile where user can look at their profile details, when the user clicks the button 'edit profile' they are brought to /editprofile and is able to update their profile with a form. Once they click on the button 'update', editProfile() function is called and the api updates the details respectively then navigates the user back to /studentprofile. However, once the user goes back to /studentprofile their old data is only shown and you have to manually reload the page to see the updated data, is there any way to fix this so the user don't have to reload the page themselves?

Here is the code of /editprofile. I am using react router dom v6.3.0

```
function StudentEdit() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("")

    const data = {
        student_name: name,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        description: description
    }

    function editProfile() {
        const studentid = localStorage.getItem('studentid')
        api.put(`/students/${studentid}`, data)
        .then(
            navigate('/studentProfile')
            
        )
    }
   
    return (
        <div className={editstyle.box}>
            <form className={editstyle.form}>
                <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
                <input type='text' className={editstyle.input} placeholder='Name' onChange = {(e) => setName(e.target.value)} id ="postName" value={name}></input>
                <input type='text' className={editstyle.input} placeholder='Email' onChange = {(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} id ="postEmail" value={email}></input>
                <input type='password' className={editstyle.input} placeholder='Password' onChange = {(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} id ="postPassword" value={password}></input>
                <input type='text' className={editstyle.input} placeholder='Description' onChange = {(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} id ="postDescription" value={description}></input>
                <div className={editstyle.btncol}>
                    <button type="update" className={editstyle.btn} onClick={() => editProfile()}>Update</button>
                    <button type="reset" className={editstyle.btn}>Discard Changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default StudentEdit;
```

here is the component of /studentprofile

```
function StudentProfile() {
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState([])

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProfile = async () => {
            try {
                const studentid = localStorage.getItem('studentid')
                const response = await api.get(`/students/${studentid}`);
                setProfile(response.data);
            } catch (err) {
                if (err.response) {
                    console.log(err.response.data);
                } else {
                    console.log(`error: ${err.message}`)
                }
            }
        }
        fetchProfile()
    }, [])

    const delProfile = async () => {
        try {
          const studentid = localStorage.getItem('studentid')
          await api.delete(`/students/${studentid}`);
          navigate('/home');        
          } catch (err) {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
    }


    return(
        <div>
            {profile.map(profiles => (
                <Profile key={profiles.student_id} profiles={profiles} delProfile={delProfile}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default StudentProfile;
```

app.js routing

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar/>

            <BrowserRouter>
                  <Routes>
                    <Route path="/studentprofile" element={<StudentProfile/>}/>
                    <Route path="/studentEdit" element={<StudentEdit/>}/>
                  </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]. From what I see, or can guess, it is that your app doesn't refetch the updated data after backend data is updated. This isn't really an issue with `react-router-dom` so much as it is a logical issue maintaining/synchronizing data. You can either refetch the data (*probably what you want to do*) or you can optimistically update the local student state upon successful PUT request. Either way, we need to see more of what your app code is *actually* doing to provide more optimal suggestions.

Comment: @DrewReese My apologies, I have edited my post and added in more of my app code.

Comment: Can you include the component that is rendered on route `path="/studentProfile"` so we can see what it does when mounted? Can you also include the code that holding the fetched "student" data that is being rendered/updated?

Comment: Just so I understand the code, the endpoint ```api.get(`/students/${studentid}`);``` returns ***all*** student profiles? And they get stored in the `profile` state that is an array and mapped to `Profile`? Is the `profile` state the state what isn't updating when you edit a student object/data? How does one get from `StudentProfile` to `StudentEdit`? Are these components rendered on any routes? Can you share the routing/navigation as part of your [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese the endpoint api.get returns only one profile based on the id in the localstorage. Yes, it is stored in the profile state and then mapped to Profile. Yes, the state does not update when I edited the student data so I have to refresh the page then it would only be updates. The components are rendered on Routes in app.js. I will share the routing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue now, the `form` element in the `StudentEdit` component isn't having the default form action prevented which is reloading the page and React app.

The "update" button has an invalid `type` attribute value. The only valid `type` attribute values are `"submit"` (*which is the default value*), `"button"`, and `"reset"`. I suspect the form is being submitted and reloading the React app.

Fix the update button's `type` attribute and prevent the `form` element's default form action.

Another issue is the `api.put` Promise chain, the `.then` has an invalid callback, it's immediately invoking the `navigate` function. This should be a proper callback function.

Example:

```
function StudentEdit() {
  ...

  function editProfile(e) { // <-- receive `onSubmit` event object
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent the default action

    const studentid = localStorage.getItem("studentid");
    api.put(`/students/${studentid}`, data)
      .then(() => navigate("/studentProfile")); // <-- callback calls `navigate`
  }

  return (
    <div className={editstyle.box}>
      <form
        className={editstyle.form}
        onSubmit={editProfile} // <-- editProfile is onSubmit handler
      >

        ...

        <div className={editstyle.btncol}>
          <button
            type="submit" // <-- type="submit" here to submit form
            className={editstyle.btn}
          >
            Update
          </button>
          <button type="reset" className={editstyle.btn}>
            Discard Changes
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-v6-usenavigate-need-to-refresh-page-to-show-new-data]

Comment: Hi, I did what you said but I am getting an error:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')

Comment: @NTACO The `onSubmit` event object should exist if you moved `editProfile` to the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler *and* consume it in the callback, i.e. the `e` passed to `editProfile`.

Comment: Yup I did that. It worked and the page did reload but oddly enough, the error still exists.

Comment: @NTACO Which error? The original issue with data, or the form submission issue?

Comment: The data works fine. When I submitted the form, I'm not sure why there's an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')  at editProfile 
  at onClick

Comment: @NTACO I see. Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Answer (score -8):

Try `mobx` or `zustand` it may suit your need better